# SQL - how do I group by Acct_Num that have > 3 records of R_CDE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with several columns. I want to query the account numbers in column Acct_Num that have three or more (>3) records in column R_CDE, how do I go about that?
I tried that but it gives me this error:
Msg 8120, Level 16
Column 'table.dbo.0813.RECORD_TYPE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any ideas?

Comment: `GROUP BY ...` with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 3`

Comment: I tried that but it gives me this error:
Msg 8120, Level 16
Column 'table.dbo.0813.RECORD_TYPE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post (add to your question by using [edit]) the exact query you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Wrap RECORD_TYPE with an [aggregate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)
2. Add RECORD_TYPE to the GROUP BY clause
3. Remove RECORD_TYPE from the SELECT statement

What the error is essentially saying is that you haven't specified what RECORD_TYPE you want to display on the rows which are grouped by Acct_Num?

Any columns in the select statement either have to be present in your GROUP BY clause or be "wrapped" in an aggregate function:

```
SELECT
    Acct_Num,                 -- no aggregate function since in GROUP BY clause
    max(dbo.0813.RECORD_TYPE) -- aggregate function required
FROM ...
GROUP BY Acct_Num

SELECT
    Acct_Num,                 
    dbo.0813.RECORD_TYPE      -- error: Msg 8120, Level 16 Column 'table.dbo.0813.RECORD_TYPE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
FROM ...
GROUP BY Acct_Num
```

If the RECORD_TYPE will always be the same for a single Acct_Num then MIN() or MAX() would be fine.